# A problem on showing the existence of a sequence of sets with some property

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $S^1=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}.$ Sets $A,B \subset S^1$ are said to be $congruent$ if there exists a number $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $B=\{ze^{i \alpha}:z \in A \},$ that is, B "is obtained from A by a rotation through an angle $\alpha.$"

Prove that there exists a sequence $\{E_n \}_{n \ge 1}$ of pairwise disjoint and congruent sets such that $$S^1=\bigcup_{n \ge 1}E_n.$$

**My attempt:**

We know that $S^1$ is uncountable. Since, we need $S^1=\bigcup_{n \ge 1}E_n,$ we have that $E_n$ is uncountable for at least one $n.$ But congruence of the sequence $\{E_n \}_{n \ge 1}$ gives that for each $n \ge 1,$ we have that $E_n$ is uncountable.

I am stuck here as to how to proceed. Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_1 = e^{i\theta_1}$ for $\theta_1 \in [0,\pi)$ and $E_2 = e^{i\theta_2}$ for $\theta_2 \in [\pi, 2\pi)$. These are disjoint, congruent using $\alpha = \pi$, and their union is $S_1$.

Edit: this doesn't show there is an infinite sequence with this property which takes more effort. Here's one way:

Write a list of all the rational numbers $x_i \in Q, 0 \leq x < 1$. We can break up the unit circle into $2^\ell$ sets of the form

$$\left[ 2\pi \frac{m}{2^\ell}, 2\pi \frac{m + 1}{2^\ell}\right), 0 \leq m < 2^\ell$$

The idea is to write each $E_n$ as a countable union of all the sets that contain $x_n$ as follows. Define

$$c_\ell(x) = \left[ 2\pi \frac{m_x}{2^\ell}, 2\pi \frac{m_x + 1}{2^\ell}\right)$$

where $m_x$ indicates the interval containing $x$. This function is well defined since the sets are disjoint. Now let

$$E_n = \bigcup_{\ell = 1}^\infty c_\ell(x_n)$$

This is a bijection between $n$ and the countable unions:

- Every set $c_\ell(x)$ starts at a rational, so it is onto
- For any two distinct $x_i$, $x_j$ there is some $\ell$ such that $c_\ell(x_i)$ contains $x_i$ but not $x_j$, so it is one-to-one

Comment: Yes. This is true for a finite number of sets $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n,$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ But in this question, we need a sequence $\{E_n \}$ with the required property. Please help.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood but just updated with an idea.